# dropdown boxes in RSelenium

Tags: r, selenium-webdriver, rselenium

How can one interact with dropdown boxes in `RSelenium`? In particular, I can select the dropdown box using `findElement` but how does one select an option with it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

here is the code to select a drop down list based on xpath.

Since the dropdown is inside an iframe, I have to switch into that iframe first. 
It probably is much easier in your situation.

New to RSelenium, check out the [quick start tutorial](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/basics.html), want to learn more about the function, refer to the pdf [documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/RSelenium.pdf).

```
require(RSelenium)
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4444, browserName = "firefox")

remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select")

iframe <- remDr$findElement(using='id', value="iframeResult")
remDr$switchToFrame(iframe)

# change audi to whatever your option value is
option <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//*/option[@value = 'audi']")
option$clickElement()
```

[image]

Comment: I do not switch the Frame,and I directly use the xpath to change the 'select' option,it works.Thanks a lot.