# How to use package Rselenium? css selector drop-down list element

Tags: javascript, r, web-scraping, css-selectors, rselenium

Maybe my question is a little basic, but know very little programming. I'm trying to automate the downloading of data from the next page (it is a page of the Chilean government, so the data are public) With the package Rselenium

[Odepa historic prices website](http://apps.odepa.cl)

I learned a little about selecting items and clicking a few. But I do not know how to address a drop-down list

```
    RSelenium::checkForServer()
    RSelenium::startServer(args = c("-port 4455"),
     log = FALSE, invisible = FALSE)
    # RSelenium::startServer() if required
    require(RSelenium)
    remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost" 
                          , port = 4444
                          , browserName = "chrome"
    )
    remDr$open()

    remDr$getStatus()

    remDr$getCurrentUrl()

    remDr$refresh()

    remDr$navigate("http://apps.odepa.cl/SeriesHistoricasParams")

    table <- remDr$findElement(using='id', value="table")
    remDr$switchToFrame(table)

    option <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//*/option[@value = '01']")
```

If anyone could help me select options from the drop-down lists that appear, it would be appreciated. Please be clear, I understand very little programming, I use R for statistical analysis.

### Update

I could select the first item in the list and select OK. My problem, the rest of the list has the same names "selector40" so I do not know how to identify them correctly. I think I should edit the section of the code

```
"//*/option[@value = '01']"
```

But I do not know how

[image]

Here my **sessionInfo()**

```
    R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
    Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
    Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

    locale:
      [1] LC_CTYPE=es_CL.UTF-8      
    [2] LC_NUMERIC=C              
    [3] LC_TIME=es_CL.UTF-8       
    [4] LC_COLLATE=es_CL.UTF-8    
    [5] LC_MONETARY=es_CL.UTF-8   
    [6] LC_MESSAGES=es_CL.UTF-8   
    [7] LC_PAPER=es_CL.UTF-8      
    [8] LC_NAME=C                 
    [9] LC_ADDRESS=C              
    [10] LC_TELEPHONE=C            
    [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=es_CL.UTF-8
    [12] LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

    attached base packages:
      [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils    
    [5] datasets  methods   base     

    loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
      [1] rsconnect_0.4.3 tools_3.3.1    
    > library(RSelenium)
    Loading required package: RCurl
    Loading required package: bitops
    Loading required package: RJSONIO
    Loading required package: XML
    > sessionInfo()
    R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
    Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
    Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

    locale:
      [1] LC_CTYPE=es_CL.UTF-8      
    [2] LC_NUMERIC=C              
    [3] LC_TIME=es_CL.UTF-8       
    [4] LC_COLLATE=es_CL.UTF-8    
    [5] LC_MONETARY=es_CL.UTF-8   
    [6] LC_MESSAGES=es_CL.UTF-8   
    [7] LC_PAPER=es_CL.UTF-8      
    [8] LC_NAME=C                 
    [9] LC_ADDRESS=C              
    [10] LC_TELEPHONE=C            
    [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=es_CL.UTF-8
    [12] LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

    attached base packages:
      [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils    
    [5] datasets  methods   base     

    other attached packages:
      [1] RSelenium_1.3.5 XML_3.98-1.4    RJSONIO_1.3-0  
    [4] RCurl_1.95-4.8  bitops_1.0-6   

    loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
      [1] rsconnect_0.4.3 tools_3.3.1     caTools_1.17.1
```

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26963927/dropdown-boxes-in-rselenium) might help if you know which drop down option you want to select.

Comment: I tried with that answer before, but my object "selector40" is not an iframe. I think it's a table. Sorry if I misspoke