# R - Rselenium - navigate drop down menu / list / box using = 'id'

Tags: r, xpath, drop-down-menu, rselenium

How can I navigate a dynamic drop down list via " using = 'id' "     (e.g., `remDr$findElement(using='id', value="main_ddYear")` ?

I can find and click using `findElement`.  After clicking I could send "down arrow" keys (keystrokes) and an "enter" if I know how many arrows down my targeted selection is.

Sample of the page source

```
<select name="main$ddYear" onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;main$ddYear\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" id="main_ddYear" class="groupTextBox">
<option selected="selected" value="2017">2017</option>
<option value="2016">2016</option>
<option value="2015">2015</option>
<option value="2014">2014</option>
<option value="2013">2013</option>
</select>
```

I would like to do something similar to the solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26963927/dropdown-boxes-in-rselenium) but with 'id' instead of 'xpath' .  I could not adapt the xpath solution.

[Another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232544/selenium-webdriver-and-dropdown-boxes) in Java used a "Select" class which I did not find referenced in the [quick start tutorial](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-basics.html#sending-text-to-elements) or [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/RSelenium.pdf).

I will post a separate question about how to scrape the drop down list of options / values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With a little knowledge about XPath, adapting the linked solution which using XPath for your case should be straightforward, for example :

```
option <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//select[@id='main_ddYear']/option[@value='2014']")
option$clickElement()
```

**Brief explanation about the XPath :**

- **`//select[@id='main_ddYear']`** : Find `<select>` element, anywhere in the HTML, where `id` attribute value equals `'main_ddYear'`
- **`/option[@value = '2014']`** : From such `<select>` element, return child `<option>` where `value` attribute value equals `'2014'`.

Comment: This is the easiest way to do it (target and click the appropriate option). You can use css selectors as an alternative `remDr$findElement("css", "#main_ddYear option[value='2014']")`

Comment: Both worked. I used the css selector so the comment by @jdharrison was quite useful. Two questions: 1) earlier research pointed me to focus on css selectors versus xpath.  Do you both agree with this?  2) I found what I thought were good web resources on using css selectors but did not find reference to the syntax/technique by jdharrison.  Can you recommend a definitive reference.   If this is common technique, perhaps my search terms were poor.