# RSelenium fails to find element on page with dropdowns

Tags: r, rselenium

I'm trying to scrape some data from table that uses dropdowns. The table is, "GIC options". The "Term" is "Mid-Term" and the "Interest Type" is "Compound".

Looking at the SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39713466/r-rselenium-navigate-drop-down-menu-list-box-using-id), I tried:

```
library(RSelenium)
remDr <- remoteDriver(port = 4445L)
remDr$navigate("https://www.nbc.ca/personal/savings-investments/gic/non-redeemable.html")
webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", '//*[@class="ft2-dropdown-list-element"]/option[@value="Mid-Term"]')
```

and a css version

```
webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "css", "#ft2-filterDropdownBtnID option[value='Mid-Term']")
```

Both result in `Selenium message:Unable to locate element`

How can I scrape the data in this table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below my solution.

```
library(RSelenium)
driver <- rsDriver(browser=c("firefox"),port = 4445L)
remote_driver <- driver[["client"]]  
remote_driver$navigate("https://www.nbc.ca/personal/savings-investments/gic/non-redeemable.html")

#Active the box by a click
remote_driver$findElement(using = "css selector", '.ft2-dropdown-btn-label')$clickElement()

#Now you can choose what you need
remote_driver$findElement(using = "xpath", '//*[@id="ft2"]/div[2]/div/ul/li[3]/a')$clickElement()

#All
//*[@id="ft2"]/div[2]/div/ul/li[1]/a
#Short term
//*[@id="ft2"]/div[2]/div/ul/li[2]/a
#Mid term
//*[@id="ft2"]/div[2]/div/ul/li[3]/a
#Long term
//*[@id="ft2"]/div[2]/div/ul/li[4]/a

#To scrape the value of the table, below a possible solution.
webElem <- remote_driver$findElement(using = "css selector", 'div.table-wrapper:nth-child(4) > table:nth-child(1)')
webElem$getElementText()
```

Comment: How did you derive these xpaths, //*[@id="ft2"]/div[2]/div/ul/li[1]/a etc...

Comment: I derived it after the click the list.